# System Error:An Overrun of a stack-based buffer in windows system file explorer.exe

Tags: windows, buffer, explorer, system-error, stack-based

I'm having an issue with windows. when I opened it, the screen is getting black every time and refreshes it. I opened it in safe mode and the error is showing that  **An Overrun of a stack-based buffer in Explorer.exe. Please Help me to fix it.**

The complete Error is:

**The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in this application (explorer.exe).This overrun could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this application**

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you'll need to reinstall windows on top of itself using a Windows setup file, but to get the setup file on your desktop, follow these steps

Boot into normal mode

Ctrl+Shift+Esc for task manager

File

Run new task

Type "services.msc" and run with admin rights

When Service Manager pops up, scroll to "Windows Error Reporting Service", right-click, then stop the service.

This should prevent the constant explorer refreshing to allow you to transfer your windows files onto the desktop and run.

After you run the Windows installer it should fix your issue